# How to pass to views amount of user nodes variable?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am trying to make a view with users who added most nodes. I want to sort them by the amount of added nodes of a specific content type.

Is there any chance to count this in Views? Should I pass the variable from module? How can I do this variable pass to views?

I don't have any idea on how to make this trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [User Stats](https://www.drupal.org/project/user_stats) module. I've done exactly this before with it, worked like a charm. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> Provides commonly requested user statistics for themers, IP address tracking and Views integration. Statistics are:
>
> - days registered;
> - join date;
> - days since last login;
> - days since last post;
> - post count;
> - login count;
> - user online/offline;
> - IP address;